# Почему бы разработчикам браузеров не сделать инъекцию

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, angularjs, javascript

Почему бы разработчикам браузеров не сделать инъекцию популярных  js библиотек, фреймворков?, дабы не качать от куда то, просто вызвать как любой объект или метод javascript, ведь уже меньше будет запросов на сервак, или возникнут какие то проблемы? Если нужна более новая версия к примеру того же angular, можно уже просто тогда загрузить.

Google CDN - я знаю, это все же запрос, лишний

Comment: Настало время вам познакомиться с Google CDN

Comment: @Fikret: А кто будет определять, какая библиотека популярная? Кто будет выбирать, включать для всех стабильную версию или edge? Как избежать dll hell: со старой версией сайт работает, а с новой нет?

Comment: @Fikret, идея, конечно, соблазнительна, но противоречит принципу несвязанности. Браузер предоставляет интерфейс, библиотеки его используют. Не должно быть никакой взаимосвязи между браузером и библиотекой, иначе это рано или поздно обернется проблемами совместимости (да и даже сейчас браузеры ведут себя совсем не одинаково).

Comment: Смертельную инъекцию. Нафигачили зоопарк браузеров и ни одного нормального.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея плоха вот чем: во-первых, средний пользователь интернета, выходит, станет скачивать себе по копии каждой из популярных библиотек, не пропуская ни одного апдейта, даже если ни разу ей не воспользуется.

В то время, как с популярными CDN от Google, Yandex, Cloudflare и производителей этих библитек, скачивается только действительно нужная библиотека, когда она нужна. И, что важно, остаётся в кэше только того браузера, где ей пользуются.

Во-вторых, не всякий разработчик сайта/страниц предусмотрит наличие встроенной в браузер копии нужной библиотеки, как приоритетный вариант, пропускающий загрузку её с CDN.

Итого, **выигрышь** от вашего предложения: экономия времени при загрузке страниц, содержащих популярные библиотеки и предусмотревших «новую» фичу браузеров. Например, jQuery с Google CDN у меня сейчас загрузился за 70ms — их бы сэкономили.

**Проигрышь**: лишний трафик при обновлении браузера.

Т.е. там выигрываем миллисекунды, там проигрываем. Стоит ли игра свеч, зависит от общей картины использования. Теоретически возможна ситуация, когда выигрышь превзойдёт затраты. Но точно не в 10 раз и более (моя оценка на глаз). Поэтому я – против.

Comment: Ну почему сразу плоха-то? Вы только представьте - все популярные сайты встроены сразу в браузер. Т.е. даже при отсутствии интернета всегда можно открыть сайт - одни мобилки сколько на интернете сэкономят )

А если браузеры еще и предсказывать будут - как будет выглядеть сайт завтра, то тогда ваще хорошо же станет ) Пришел заказчик, говорит - мне надо это, это и это. Ты открываешь в браузере сайт - там уже все это есть, сохраняешь где надо - и отдаешь заказчику )

Красота же ))

Comment: обхохочешься прям

Comment: @Fikret, ну я просто вашу мысль развил. Чем библиотека отличается от сайта? По сути только бэкэндом и все. Поэтому почему бы не перенести вашу мысль на более общую задачу? Я это и сделал )

Comment: > Стоит ли игра свеч
Почему не свечь?